# One to one question

Tags: colleagues, manager, teamwork

I am based in the UK.

I have a very poor relationship with my manager. She doesn't like me and I don't like her but no option this is the structure.

She joined the company in 2017 and I left the team in 2018 because of her but had to go back to the same team in 2019.

I kept everything in writing with all of our comms. We did try to start speaking briefly late 2019 and arguments started again so went back to go back keeping everything in writing again.

I kept notes of the arguments and some are disrespectful, discriminatory and insulting. I should have done a grievance procedure but didn't but took notes.

She is useless, can't manage, and dependent on me. She wants to start one on meetings again.

Can I refuse to attend and insist that it should be in writing? If a meeting is needed it must have a clear agenda on what they are such as issues and concerns so anything that needs to be discussed are known upfront and fully in investigated and answered during the meeting?

Obviously the downside is career progression but that's blown away long time ago when is a manager. 
Senior managers are probably aware of the problems. How would they feel if I decline the 1-1 meetings with only the essential said in the above paragraph? Such as I wish to continue in writing but meetings necessary only about specific topics with full details given upfront in writing.

Comment: What are your career plans, are you just weathering in this company until you can find a greener pasture?

Comment: Hi there, yes. Just hanging around and definitely not looking for  a progress higher up. 

My concerns are is there a performance issue or conduct issue if I decline? If she wants to meet she should specifically include an agenda on what she wants to talk about. I will even say given the past conduct I will not attend meetings that isnt focused or specific allowing the discussions to deviate.

Comment: @Tryingtosurvive Do you have a case on her? Officially, that is? You cannot otherwise force her to set an agenda, as she is your boss and an uncooperative one at that. Only if she is forced to do so by someone up the hierarchy, you might have a chance.

Comment: Is there a union, in your industry, that could provide help and support?

Comment: Hi - I am part of an union. But I haven't approached yet. Do you think I should do now or wait until the threat of disciplinary or if she pulls up a performance plan on me?

Comment: *...so went back to go back keeping everything in writing again.* Was that by an explicit agreement where one or both of you said, "Let's stick to emails", or did you both just stop talking to each other? Also, what's the nature of these arguments? Is it disagreements on an approach to the work, your performance, etc.? Are you arguing about behavior, work place rules?

Comment: I just read through the comments below and: *"The HR person seemed reasonable and told me that I should raise a grievance procedure but should also explain on what I want to happen etc. I didn't and left it at that."* Why didn't you file a grievance?

Comment: Hi, We just stopped talking except adhoc where it was absolutely necessary. I just didn't bother to raise a grievance process. Just incase it comes as a complaint that would seem unimportant for an investigative manager. Also I am required to provide a solution as part of grievance. I dont know what the alternative solution is. I have listed details of the complaint in one of the comments below on another post.

Answer (score 8):

To be honest, I'm not sure 100% of the blame belongs on your manager here.  You're not coming across as composed and professional, especially with some of the particular questions you're asking (can I refuse to meet with the boss, can I refuse to talk about subjects not in a written agenda, etc) as well as your characterization of her (useless, incompetent, discriminatory, insulting, etc).  It's kinda a bit red-flaggy.  **I'm not saying this as an issue of blame** - just a recommendation that you also look inside to see if there's anything you can do to deescalate or get a better rapport with your manager, because I have my doubts this is on just one side of the fence.

Now, that said?

No, you can't refuse 1-on-1 meetings with your boss.  No, you can't refuse to talk about anything that isn't in a written agenda.  Etc.

If you really need to try to get all communication in writing?  Then send a 'making sure I understand' email whenever you have a meeting.  You and your boss talk about needing to work on the Floobar project, needing to complete the XYZ task by week-end, and examining a better way of dealing with ABC?  Then write notes during the meeting, and then send an email like:

> Alice Alicia,
>
> Per our meeting, I'll put in some time with the Floobar project, and
>   make sure I get XYZ done by week end.  I'll also spend an hour or two
>   trying to figure out a better way of handling the ABC problem.
>
> -- Trying

This gets things in written form, and is a good way of making sure you and your boss are on the same page.

***EDIT - based on your comments on this answer, and your self-answer (before it was deleted)***

I'm getting more convinced this is more on your side of the fence than hers.

Let me explain why.  In your comments, you wrote two examples of 'egregious' behavior from her:

> She said "Make sure you drink one beer, don't buy food for friends,
>   take a pen and paper with you" when I was going to a conference.

... and ...

> There was also comments such as "I am your manager and you do what I
>   say" in 2018 also.

These aren't exactly smoking guns here.  I mean, seriously - the first is something every relatively new-to-labor person should be told before going to a conference (don't get wasted, don't use company expense meals on friends, bring supplies) - to the point where if my manager said it to me *as a senior in the labor force for 17 years*, I'd just blink, shrug, and nod.  It's common sense professionalism.  If you're getting upset at *this*...

Likewise... she *is* your manager.  Seriously.  Unless she's asking you to do something illegal/unethical, *your job is to do what she says.*  You can bring up disagreements with her, but at the end of the day, the performance of the area is her responsibility, and she's in charge of making the strategic decisions.  A manager saying "I'm your manager, do what I say" is... well, just as often the case of someone refusing to take direction from their boss.

This kinda dovetails with what you were suggesting in your self-answer: letting your performance suffer in order to highlight her supposed incompetence - even risking disciplinary action for it!  I can't tell you how wrong-headed this is.

Anyway, contrast her behavior (which, honestly... doesn't sound too bad) with the sheer drama of you're describing (mental anguish, a ruined easter, etc, etc) - I'd change my suggestion to:

**Find another job.  You won't have to deal with her (and she won't have to deal with you) - and work on being a better employee at the next spot**... because if your attitude is "Try to make the boss look bad" and "Don't feel you need to do what the boss says", you're probably going to have strained relations at the next post as well.

Comment: Thanks for this. 

I do have problems of my own too and definitely not perfect. Keeping my composure and not raising voice is essentially what you are saying. 
When there is a fundamental problem with two people who don't get along these behavior can and will get worse and potentially being ended up on the disciplinary panel because of this. It is this I am trying to avoid by avoiding the 1-1.

Comment: Here is a quick example, one of the problems out of several was the way she spoke to me in one to one in 2018. She said "Make sure you drink one beer, don't buy food for friends, take a pen and paper with you" when I was going to a conference. There was also comments such as "I am your manager and you do what I say" in 2018 also. It is a series of these things that led to argument and eventually her old boss had me reported to him direct and spoken to her about her behavior. When her new boss started, who is NOT aware of the entire history of the series of events, asked me to go back to her.

Comment: I have dealt everything by email over the last few months (and by cc'n) her boss too - she also cc her boss with everything that she sends to me in 2019. 
There are still times I speak to her ad-hoc and in one such meeting she said "It wasn't on" (presumably saying the issues happened between us in 2018) and said the beer, pen/paper comment again before I was going to a different conference in 2019. This is a clear sign of vindictive behavior and I feel trapped in this.

Comment: She also admitted to me in late 2019 that "She told her boss that she didn't want me in the team" but her boss said "She should take him". Is this even an acceptable things to say to me what she discussed with her about me? I have not said this to her boss yet - How would he react to her that she is upsetting her staff about saying things like this? In any case I have recorded this, if someone thinks I am lying - it can't be because how could I have know what they discussed between the two of them except her telling me.

Comment: The issue had gone for too long and it simply isn't possible to build rapport with each other - I have tried several times but they failed and she does not come across as trustworthy. Her previous two bosses, who I had a good relationship and have left the company, even told  me that there is an issue with her culture - she is native Chinese - I don't know why this should be my problem.

Comment: I invited her boss to discuss about her in February and he didn't respond so I took the matter to HR on a confidential basis. The HR person seemed reasonable and told me that I should raise a grievance procedure but should also explain on what I want to happen etc. I didn't and left it at that.

Comment: More importantly my dealings with her is causing a great deal of mental anguish, I cannot focus on anything except the problems between me and her and do not wish to go through the same issues again. Hence, the reason why I thought if it is compulsory to have one to one the least that can happen given the history should be an agenda to keep the focused, followed by notes on what was discussed. 

If it were go to disciplinary panel, how would they react given all this has happened? I work for a large organisation.

Comment: (sorry had to Add Comment in different sections as there seems to be a word count on this)

Answer (score 5):

To me, it sounds like the two of you are too far gone to try to reconcile, especially as you plan to move on as soon as you can. If not for that there are some strategies I could suggest employing. Though as you cannot get along, at least You, OP, should remain professional.

> I kept notes of the arguments and some are disrespectful,
>   discrimanstory and insultive. I should have done a grievance procedure
>   but didn't but took notes.

It is too late now. One-sided notes are only good for anything when fresh and meticulously kept, and as a lot of time has passed since, and it was in the past, you've missed your window on that. You have to understand that you are not a court typist sworn in to record the truth, instead what you have is your interpretation of events that happened. 
Best to let it go and try to be as professional as you can be.

> Can I refuse to attend and insist that it should be in writing?

You can but I would not recommend that. The problem with refusing to meet is that in at least some eyes it will make you the unreasonable one, as you are refusing to do something as rudimentary as a 1-1.

There are a few strategies you can employ though to help you. The most obvious one for me is to explain at the start of the meeting that you want to record it, then produce your smartphone and ask if she minds. No need for any more explanation than that, don't bring in the past, and if she asks why just say that you like to keep minutes of your meetings, and this is the most accurate way to do it.

That alone generally will make anyone behave above board, but if not, you will now have a recording you can produce to your boss and explain that you will only meet with that person when the meeting will go in a more professional manner.

I also must touch on something:

> She is useless, cant manage, and dependent on me.

There are always two sides to any story, and it is never as simple as you portray it in this one sentence. The fault may not be even, but it's almost always shared between both sides to some extend, so I highly recommend to give her benefit of the doubt, and at least try to let go of the past, if for no other reason than it will make your life easier.

Comment: The idea of a recording dies in its tracks when the manager does not accept it. Furthermore: "There are always two sides to any story..." - yes, indiscriminately taking that position is what permits bullies to continue bullying for extended periods. While it is often true, it is sometimes plainly untrue: the "other side" is simply wrong, period. And putting the foot down is the only thing that will make the bullying go away. I do not make a judgement about the present case. While you may be right here, I disagree with "never that simple". Sometimes it is. I agree with "let go of the past.."

Answer (score 2):

> Can I refuse to attend and insist that it should be in writing?

This would invite disciplinary action.

> She is useless, cant manage, and dependent on me. She wants to start one on meetings again.

Plenty of managers are like this, but they're the ones in a position to discipline you, not the other way around.

> How would they feel if I decline the 1-1 meetings with only the essential said in the above paragraph?

It would highlight that there is an issue, but it would also highlight that you think you can dictate terms to the hierarchy. It then becomes an equation of how valuable you actually are, versus how much of a headache will you cause.

If you're actively job searching and have decided you want to leave, then I would advise just keeping your head down and complying until you can leave. If you are not sure, then make up your mind or expect things to keep deteriorating. You're in charge of your own career in broad strokes, no one else has the same stake in it. You're just a value/headache equation to everyone else unless you have a personal connection.